# TYPO3 TCA how to set pages max title length

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-tca

our customer needs super long page titles. in the backend i found `Configuration > TCA > pages > columns > title > config > max`

so this would be the correct setting to increase the page title length right? but where can i add the mandatory TCA to increase the length and how would it look like?

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the TCA settings with PageTS (`TCEFORM`).

Documentation is here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

Example for your issue:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header.config.max = <your value>
```

But be sure that the table field in the DB may be increased as well.
Then you need to add an `ext_tables.sql` file in your sitepackage extension and add:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pages (
    title VARCHAR(<your value) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: so TCA settings with PageTS. i need the setting for some subpages, so i go to the parent page > template > edit the whole template record > and there below in "Setup" is the so called PageTS - is this correct?

Comment: nvm, found it in the docs. would be parent page > edit > resources > PageTS

Comment: alright i changed the "visual" limit of the input to 1000 (TCEFORM) and the colum is now varchar(10000)...  but the field does still get somehow trimmed, i can set a veeery long title but there is still a limit somewhere - i can also edit the database colum manually and insert a very long title - save it - reload the frame and the title is still trimmed - what is this limit?

Comment: so now i can edit my child pages - enter a very long title - hit save (its valid for input and database) and it only saves a trimmed version of length 57

Comment: the SEO extension was the problem by setting a custom max value

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is correct?
My approach is this:

```
TCEFORM.pages.title.config {
    max = 250
    size = 250
}
```

It also works in the form, but it still gets truncated on save.
I have deleted caches.
What have I overlooked?

Comment: Make sure you add the column width changes to SQL (see Thomas' answer)

Comment: My approach was right, that's how it works.
I only had the extension cs_seo in and it has a limit of 57 on the title.